# how do I multiply integers in a set?

Tags: python, loops, set

You are given a sequence of positive ints where every element appears three times, except one that appears only once (let's call it x) and one that appears only twice (let's call it y).
Your task is to find x * x * y.

e.g.
arr = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4]   -> 4 x 4 x 3

I have written some code below. I have a question regarding the final part of the code- so after the completion of the loop, there should be one integer left in seen_once and one integer left in seen_twice, but how do I then multiply these numbers, as they are now sitting in a set()?

```
 def Missing_Values(arr):
     seen_once = set()
     seen_twice = set()
     seen_thrice = set()

     for i in arr:
         if i not in seen_once or seen_twice or seen_thrice:
             seen_once.add(i)

         elif i in seen_once:
             seen_twice.add(i)
             seen_once.remove(i)

         elif i in seen_twice:
             seen_thrice.add(i)
             seen_twice.remove(i)

     return seen_once*seen_once*seen_twice

 Missing_Values(arr)
```

Comment: I think it has been asked before, but can find it. Short answer is: `n = myset.pop()`  and there is another alternative `n = next(iter(myset))`. The former removes the item from the set.

Comment: See also the Counter: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia a set is not subscriptable, this will cause an exception.

Comment: Do you have to use `loop` way? What if the list is very huge then?  (more like follow-up question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to `pop` the values.

```
x = seen_once.pop()
y = seen_twice.pop()
return x * x * y
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `counter` from `collections` for better **performance** that also improves **readability**.

Following is the code:

```py
from collections import Counter

arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
d = Counter(arr)

ans = 1
for x, cnt in d.items():
    if cnt == 2:
        ans *= x
    elif cnt == 1:
        ans *= (x * x)
print(ans)
```

You can also use **list comprehension** as a **generator** as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4]
d = Counter(arr)

x, y = (x**(3 - cnt) for x, cnt in d.items() if(cnt <= 2))

print(x*y)
```

## Counter Explanation:

Counter returns a **dictionary** where array item as a Key and item frequency as a value. For example, if array `arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]` then counter provide following dictionary:

```
d = {
1: 3, 
2: 3, 
3: 2, 
4: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a bug in your code, this is a working piece:

```
def Missing_Values(arr):
    seen_once = set()
    seen_twice = set()
    seen_thrice = set()

    for i in arr:
        if i not in seen_once and i not in seen_twice and i not in seen_thrice: # Note this line!
            seen_once.add(i)

        elif i in seen_once:
            seen_twice.add(i)
            seen_once.remove(i)

        elif i in seen_twice:
            seen_thrice.add(i)
            seen_twice.remove(i)
    return next(iter(seen_once))*next(iter(seen_once))*next(iter(seen_twice))


arr = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4] 

print(Missing_Values(arr))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug! Don't know why I used 'or'.